# Mosquitto and PHP

Tags: php, apache, raspberry-pi, mqtt, mosquitto

I am having problem scripting in PHP to subscribe topics on Mosquitto MQTT. I am publishing from and Arduino and I can subscribe just fine from shell with mosquitto_sub, but when I am trying to subscribe from PHP script it just keeps stuck and does not show anything or if it does then it takes a million years. I tried everything available for PHP. It's the same always. I compiled my apache and php separately.

Anyone any similar experience? Any idea? Oh and all this I am doing in Raspberry-pi

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the latest JS client? http://www.eclipse.org/paho/

Here is an example of a html/js file to check everything is working, https://gist.github.com/matbor/9825309

Also, here is a simple Python WebSockets proxy for a MQTT broker. See bottom of  http://goo.gl/EBFxSQ that might run a bit better on a pi.